# Is there a better way to scroll to bottom of modal window with Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How do I scroll to the bottom of a Modal window using Puppeteer (v1.15.0)? I need to click an Accept button at the bottom of that Modal window but that button is only enabled once scrolled to the very bottom of the Modal window.  The Modal window contains a lot of text which requires scrolling given the Modal window fixed height.

For now, I am getting the button element location via `.boundingBox()` and then moving the mouse via relative pixel positions to the bottom of the modal vertical scroll bar and clicking it until I get to the bottom.  Is there a more 'native' way in Puppeteer?

Modal HTML looks something like:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Some Title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" style="height: 475px; overflow:auto;">
    <div id="msgBody">lots and lots of text...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input id="modal-option" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="option" value="Accept" disabled="disabled">
    <input id="modal-cancel" type="button" class="btn btn-warning" name="cancel" value="Decline">
</div>
```

Comment: What if you [`focus`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.5.0/docs/api.md#elementhandlefocus) the button? Is it ignored?

Comment: I'm using `hover` to scroll the button into view which scrolls the entire modal within the parent window down to get the button into view (the modal window is taller than the parent window view - so there is a scroll within a scroll) but doesn't scroll the _modal_ window.  It's a bit difficult to re-test with `focus` but I'm pretty certain if it scrolls, it also would scroll the parent window rather than the modal window.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to your last comment, both `page.click()` and `page.hover()` scroll an element into view in the same way. The [API documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options) for page.click() states:

> This method fetches an element with selector, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses page.mouse to click in the center of the element.

For page.hover():

> This method fetches an element with selector, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses page.mouse to hover over the center of the element

I'm not sure why you might be having this problem but the easiest might be to rethink your app's UX—why do you have so much content in a modal that it leads to this problem?

Comment: Thanks Kris Khaira. Re 'easiest might be to rethink your app's UX' - it's an external web site that we don't own.